# When and why does accessing CoreWindow.ActivationMode throw an InvalidCastException?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

My app has to react to a ListView's ScrollViewer's ViewChanged event, and in that event handler I want to know whether the current window has focus:

```
CoreWindow window = Window.Current.CoreWindow;
CoreWindowActivationMode mode = window.ActivationMode;
```

Unfortunately on a user's w10m device accessing `window.ActivationMode` sometimes (apparently depending on the ScrollViewer's content) throws a `System.InvalidCastException`. The documentation of the ActivationMode property does not mention any exceptions, and the exception's message is not helpful either:

```
InvalidCast_WinRT, Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow, MissingMetadataType. For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623485
```

If this is a windows/uwp bug, where should I report it?

Comment: It does not look like a UWP bug, the ActivationMode property was added in the Windows Creators update.  Be sure to set your minimum supported version to 10.0.16299.0.  Also some hint that you are assigning this property in a background thread, the only real reason that metadata plays a role that I can't think of.  I can't tell from the current docs anymore whether that is valid, it usually isn't when tinkering with CoreWindow.

Comment: I'm agree with @HansPassant's suggestion. It's a new feature introduced from 16299. If your app will be installed on the previous OS, you need to check if it's available by using [ApiInformation Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation#Windows_Foundation_Metadata_ApiInformation_IsApiContractPresent_System_String_System_UInt16_) relevant APIs before you call it.

Comment: @HansPassant oh damn, thanks a lot! Unfortunately you cannot target 16299 because W10M is still 15254. So I guess I will have to use the Window.Current.Activated event? A PlatformNotSupportedException would have been more helpful imho.

Comment: @Benni Yes. You could first check if the API is available by using [ApiInformation Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation#Windows_Foundation_Metadata_ApiInformation_IsApiContractPresent_System_String_System_UInt16_) relevant APIs, if not, you could use the Window.Current.Activated event.